# MySQL and PHP query not working correctly in php web app but works in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very interesting issue.  I have a view created in MySql that I am pulling up in my php web app.  When I do the query in the php, it give me no records but when I do the exact same query on the database I get over a 100 records.  Does anyone have any idea what the issue may be.  It seems to be real specific to my query.

```
Select * from stockview where 
    inventory_manufacturer like '%psq%' or 
    inventory_name like '%psq%' or 
    inventory_description like '%psq%' or 
    inventory_productcode like '%psq%' 
  order by menu_name ASC
```

0 records in php web app
116 records in the phpmyadmin

but if I change the search criteria to:

```
Select * from stockview where 
    inventory_manufacturer like '%scl%' or 
    inventory_name like '%scl%' or 
    inventory_description like '%scl%' or 
    inventory_productcode like '%scl%' 
  order by menu_name ASC
```

276 records in my php web app
276 records in phpmyadmin

Very weird and I am stumped.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the same table, or even the same database? Use `var_dump()` to display the exact query that PHP is submitting immediately before it submits it, to be sure that the query is what you think it is. Beyond that we'd need to see the data. Post a few lines here that exhibit the problem.

Comment: See this, and improve your question so we can help. 
 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query